# Not sure how to create a menu which uses methods from my other classes

Tags: java, oop, methods, menu

so far I have created two classes, which I will show below

I have tested both classes and they both seem to work.

I now need to create a menu which will use the two classes I have created and allow users to enter the information and to find information on their account for the following:

1. Add the customers details
2. Make a deposit to the business account
3. Record a meter reading to the business account
4. Display current balance of the business account
5. Display full account details
6. Change the discount value for the business account
7. Change the cost per unit for all business accounts
8. How to use the menu system

While I have tried my best to find out how to do it using resources online I am currently lost. Up to this point every time I have tried to create a menu system I just could not get it to work. I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me with the basics on how to go about doing it.

Thanks :)

---

```
public class GasAccount
{
    private int intAccRefNo;
    private String strName;
    private String strAddress;
    public double dblBalance;
    private double dblUnits;
    public static double dblUnitsCosts = 0.02;

    public GasAccount (int intNewAccRefNo , String strNewName , String strNewAddress)
    {
    }

    public GasAccount (int intNewAccRefNo , String strNewName , String strNewAddress , double dblNewUnits)
    {
        intAccRefNo = intNewAccRefNo;
        strName = strNewName;
        strAddress = strNewAddress;
        dblUnits = dblNewUnits;
        dblBalance = dblUnits * dblUnitsCosts;
    }

    public int getAccRefNo()
    {
        return intAccRefNo;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return strName;
    }

    public String getAddress()
    {
        return strAddress;
    }

    public void deposit(double dblDepositAmount)
    {
        dblBalance = dblBalance - dblDepositAmount;
    }

    public double getBalance()
    {
        return dblBalance;
    }

    public double getUnitCost()
    {
        return dblUnitsCosts;
    }

    public void recordUnits (double dblUnitsUsed)
    {
        dblBalance = dblBalance + dblUnitsUsed * dblUnitsCosts;
        dblUnits = dblUnitsUsed + dblUnits;
    }

    public double getUnits()
    {
        return dblUnits;
    }

    public void updateUnitsCosts(double dblNewUnitsCosts)
    {
        this.dblUnitsCosts = dblNewUnitsCosts;
    }
}
```

---

And another which extends it -

```
public class BusinessAccount extends GasAccount
{

    private double dblDiscount;

    public BusinessAccount (int intNewAccRefNo, String strNewName, String strNewAddress, double dblNewUnits, double dblNewDiscount)
    {
        super (intNewAccRefNo , strNewName , strNewAddress, dblNewUnits);
        dblDiscount = dblNewDiscount;
    }

    public void setNewDiscount(double dblNewDiscount)
    {
        dblDiscount = dblNewDiscount;
    }

    public double getDiscount()
    {
        return dblDiscount;
    }

    @Override
    public void recordUnits (double dblUnitsUsed)
    {
        double dblNewBalance;
        dblBalance = dblBalance + dblUnitsUsed * dblUnitsCosts;
        dblNewBalance = dblUnitsUsed * dblUnitsCosts * dblDiscount / 100;
        dblBalance = dblBalance - dblNewBalance;
    }
```

---

Here is what my attempted menu looks like up to the fifth option. I am doing something horribly wrong with calling in the methods from the other classes as BuisnessAccount.getMethod always shows up as an error. I am also pretty sure declaring the variables again is completely wrong as then they have no link to my other classes.

If someone could help me solve this it would be greatly appreciated

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Menu
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int Choice;

        {
            System.out.println("------------------------------");
            System.out.println ( "1. Add the customers details" ) ;
            System.out.println ( "2. Make a deposit to the business account" );
            System.out.println ( "3. Record a meter reading to the business account" ) ;
            System.out.println ( "4. Display current balance of the business account" ) ;
            System.out.println ( "5. Display full account details" ) ;
            System.out.println ( "6. Change the discount value for the business account" ) ;
            System.out.println ( "7. Change the cost per unit for all business accounts ");
            System.out.println ( "8. How to use the menu system ");
            System.out.println ( "Any other number will exit the program");
            System.out.println("------------------------------");
            System.out.println ( "\n\nEnter a number from 1 to 8" );
            Choice = input.nextInt();

            switch (Choice)
            {
             case 1 :
              int intNewAccRefNo;
              String strNewName;
              String strNewAddress;
              Double dblNewUnits;
              Double dblNewDiscount;

              System.out.println("Please enter the account number?");
              intNewAccRefNo  = input.nextInt();

              System.out.println("Please enter the account name?");
              input.nextLine();
              strNewName = input.nextLine();

              System.out.println("Please enter the account address?");
              strNewAddress = input.nextLine();

              System.out.println("Please enter the number of initial number of units used?");
              dblNewUnits = input.nextDouble();

              System.out.println("Please enter the discount?");
              dblNewDiscount = input.nextDouble();

             case 2:

              double dblDeposit;

              System.out.println("Please enter the amount you want to deposit?");
              dblDeposit = input.nextDouble();

              System.out.println ( "The current balance: " + BusinessAccount.getBalance() ) ;

             case 3:

              double dblUnits;

              System.out.println("Enter the number of Units Used");
              dblUnits = input.nextDouble();
              BusinessAccount.recordUnits(dblUnits);

             case 4:

              System.out.println("\n Current Balance: £"+ BusinessAccount.getBalance());

             case 5:

               System.out.println("Account Reference Number: " + BusinessAccount.getAccRefNo());
               System.out.println("Address: " + BusinessAccount.getAddress());
               System.out.println("Name: " + BusinessAccount.getName());
               System.out.println("Balance: " + BusinessAccount.getBalance());
               System.out.println("Discount: " + BusinessAccount.getDiscount());
               System.out.println("Units: " + BusinessAccount.getUnits());
```

---

```
case 1 :  

String strAddress;

System.out.println("Please enter the account address?"); 
strAddress = input.nextLine(); 
System.out.println("Address:" + firstAccount.getAddress());
```

There is no connection between what the user inputs and the method which i am calling, not sure how to fix.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not sure how to create a Menu which uses my other classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631050/not-sure-how-to-create-a-menu-which-uses-my-other-classes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `BusinessAccount.someMethod()`, you're attempting to call said method in a static context, but your methods are not static.  To call upon your methods, you either need to make them static or need to create an object which can then call upon them, ie:

```
BusinessAccount ba= new BusinessAccount (4, "name", "address", 3.4, 43.4);
ba.someMethodFromClass();
```

In your case, you do NOT want them to be static.  Read up more on static methods/variables (see below).

Some documentation that may be helpful: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenu.html

To answer your second question, you need to have a method (in your object's class, not main) which can assign values to your variables. ie:

```
public void setAddress (String address)
{
    strAddress=address;
}
```

Then, you'd pass the address that you read in from main into your function.  By doing that, you're initializing/assigning the value from the user to the value stored in your class, ie:

```
System.out.println("Please enter the account address?"); 
String temp = input.nextLine(); 
ba.setAddress(temp);
System.out.println("Address:" + ba.getAddress());
```

or better yet,

```
System.out.println("Please enter the account address?"); 
ba.setAddress(input.nextLine());
System.out.println("Address:" + ba.getAddress());
```

Comment: Also, your constructor/class have different names...Business vs Buisness

Comment: Ok so i've made the object and can now call the methods from my other classes. However i am now having a different problem which i have added at the bottom of my post.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by "Then, you'd pass the address that you read in from main into your function. " Would you be able to give me an example?

Comment: Edited.  Not trying to be a pain, but when people answer questions on SO, and give correct/complete answers, one (ideally) should upvote (you can upvote any number of questions/answers) answers that you think are good/accept the answer that you think best answers your question.  If you ask a question and then have additional questions, you should usually make another post.  People put their time into answering posts, and in return, they get reputation that comes from upvotes/accepted answers,etc.  Thanks.

Comment: Ah sorry, i did not realise you could upvote every answer

Comment: You can only accept one answer (by clicking the check mark), though.  Accepting answers give more reputation.  If people see that you don't upvote/accept answers, some will not answer your questions.  On that note, it takes two seconds on your part, so...

Comment: I was thinking if you accepted the answer it would essentially close the thread and I wouldn't be able to ask another question, sorry :P 

And on a side note it is now working, tyvm for your help.

Comment: No problem, man.  Glad it all worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Going off of what SteveP said, it would be a good idea to store the instances of the other classes as instance variables in the Menu class.

Also, if you're using a GUI interface, this JMenu class API may come in handy:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenu.html

Also look for JMenuBar, JMenuItem